# Does Exception Terminate Program?

Tags: php, exception

Considering the following code, run by cron:

```
try {
    $count = $stmt->execute ( $queryArray );
}
catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
    fwrite ( $fp, '  "exception" at line: ' . (__LINE__ - 3). ",  " . $ex -> getMessage () . "\n" );
    throw new RuntimeException (
         basename (__FILE__) . '::' . __METHOD__ . ' - Execute query failed: ' . $ex -> getMessage ()  );
}
```

Is re-throwing by `throw new RuntimeException` causing the program to stop? In other words, would the `catch` & `fwrite` statement sufficiently 'catch' the exception and allow the program to continue?

The `throw` documentation is vague. The only reference is to `PHP Fatal Error` from [(link to) PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is re-throwing by throw new RuntimeException causing the program to stop?

Yes, because as per the documentation there is no matching catch. In order to continue execution you would need to `catch` the second exception (`RuntimeException`) by using a nested `try/catch` which is generally not a great idea:

```
try {
   // something with PDO that generates an exception
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   // do some stuff
   try {
       throw new RuntimeException();
   } catch (RuntimeException()) {
     // do something else
   }
}
```

> In other words, would the catch & fwrite statement sufficiently 'catch' the exception and allow the program to continue?

If you want to continue with the program then you would need to not throw the second exception. However, anything that happened before you throw that exception will occur. So in your example the `fwrite` would still happen, the program would just be halted when the `RuntimeException` is encountered.

Comment: What do you mean by: 'However, and thing that happened before you throw that exception will occur. So in your example the frwite would still happen...' (typos ?) I was hoping that sentence would clear the situation for me.

Comment: Yes.. typo `s/and thing/anything` - corrected in the answer.